# Shopping Cart You have no items in your shopping cart

Tags: magento-2.1.1

I reintsalled and now i dont have any problems except this

```
    Shopping Cart
    You have no items in your shopping cart.

Click here to continue shopping.
```

when i add some items.

What can be reason?

I removed inside of `debuglog` and `systemlog` and other logs .

Also, i registered an account and when i add to `wishlist`,

```
My Wish List
You have no items in your wish list.
```

it is same again.

now i have somelogs

> for debug.lo: [2016-09-06 16:14:07] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate: 
>   {"method":"POST","url":"http: //localhost/magento/customer/account/createpost/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["wishlist_1","FPC"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false}
>   [] [2016-09-06 16:14:07] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate: 
>   {"method":"POST","url":"http: //localhost/magento/customer/account/createpost/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["wishlist_1","FPC"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false}
>   [] [2016-09-06 16:14:07] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate: 
>   {"method":"POST","url":"http: //localhost/magento/customer/account/createpost/","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"notification_update_customer_session_2"},"is_exception":false}
>   []

and others are empty for now.

```
 Copyright © 2016 Magento Commerce Inc. All rights reserved.
Magento ver. 2.1.1
```

this is success page

```
Success

Please keep this information for your records:

Magento Admin Info:

Username:
admin
Email:
admin@test.com
Password:
******
Your Store Address:
http://localhost/magento2/
Magento Admin Address:
http://localhost/magento2/admin_voa4lj/
Be sure to bookmark your unique URL and record it offline.
Encryption Key:
ed95845c46a91eee0b28e6e8d3ef1b9f
Database Info:

Database Name:
magentodb
Username:
magento
Password:
******
For security, remove write permissions from these directories: '/var/www/html/magento2/app/etc'
```

i did those

```
Flush Catalog Images Cache  Pregenerated product images files

Flush JavaScript/CSS Cache  Themes JavaScript and CSS files combined to one file

Flush Static Files Cache  Preprocessed view files and static files
Flush Magento Cache
Flush Cache Storage
```

Comment: Do you have any javascript errors on your browser developer console?

Comment: i inspect and go to console but no error. when i go to firiefox, it works. i just tried and worked.  i did not know about it. despite i cleaned ccache of  chrome and cookies.

Comment: Maybe a cached version is working in firefox, clear that cache and confirm it still works?

On Chrome you really should have an error in Developer Tools (Ctrl + Shift + i), click preserve log and reload the page.

Comment: i first time open firefx after weeeks, i dont think it is cached. no errors in chrome. i registere a user in magento in firefoxx and it works

Comment: Please, **don't try to use localhost as a top level domain**, use another domain.

Comment: for development i use? what does it can do

Comment: Yes, I remember now. Khoa is right. That was the cause of my problem when it happened to me.

Comment: Use a virtual host like store.dev, laragon is perfect for this in my opinion.

Comment: I tried docker but it gave error.  any guides for those for magento?

Comment: I encountered something similar about a month ago. Try disabling persistent cart and test.

Answer (score 2):

For me the solution was much easier. I had the cache disabled during development. Once you turn back on cache the items will appear in the shopping cart.. This worked while using a server on localhost.

Answer (score 2):

Just temporary fix. It helped me.

Comment these lines in

> src/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Cart/Add.php:80

```
if (!$this->_formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
    return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('*/*/');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not looks like a cache. But this problem is very similar to browser cookie issue. Actually it's not a problem it's just technical feature.

You need to clear browser cache https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050?hl=en.

Also you have to unset **Continue where you left off** in chrome settings.

**Please read** this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617954/chrome-doesnt-delete-session-cookies
and https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/9l-gKYIUg50/discussion

Answer (score 0):

@mik  Just only disable page cache

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by resetting browser cache and cookies (by opening an incognito window)

Comment: Please describe more because smaller line are writing on comment section.

Comment: Well sometimes answers _are_ simple. This is not a comment.